# Error mistmatch m1 and m2, what is the error on my conv layers calculations?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I have the following architecture:

```
class Net(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()

        
        # first convolutional layer
        self.conv1 = torch.nn.Conv2d(1,32,5) # (32,220,220) output tensor # (W-F)/S + 1 = (224-5)/1 + 1 = 220
        
        # first Max-pooling layer
        self.pool1 = torch.nn.MaxPool2d(2,2) # (32,110,110) output tensor
        
        # second convolutional layer
        self.conv2 = torch.nn.Conv2d(32,64,5) # (64,106,106) output tensor # (W-F)/S + 1 = (110-5)/1 + 1 = 106
        
        # second Max-pooling layer
        self.pool2 = torch.nn.MaxPool2d(2,2) # (64,53,53) output tensor
        
        # Fully connected layer
        self.fc1 = torch.nn.Linear(64*53*53, 1000)   
        self.fc2 = torch.nn.Linear(1000, 500)       
        self.fc3 = torch.nn.Linear(500, 136)        
        self.drop1 = nn.Dropout(p=0.4)
```

The images are of 224 x 224 dimensions. I'm getting the error:

> *RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [10 x 173056], m2: [179776 x 1000] at
> /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1524584710464/work/aten/src/TH/generic/THTensorMath.c:2033*

I cannot see where my error is, can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

The architecture is well, I was cropping the input image to 220 x 200 dimensions which was obviously incorrect.